# Audio glitches occur randomly

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Audio in media files randomly glitches and sometimes repeats for 1-2 seconds and then continues playing normally. These glitches seemingly happen at random times and don't recur in the same part of the audio tracks.

These glitches did not occur on Fedora 17 nor on Windows so there is nothing wrong with the hardware nor the files themselves. Tested on various media players.

I'm trying to fix this problem by installing the same audio drivers/software as Fedora has, but I don't know where to start.

Edit: I'm using GNOME 3 and I've found another audio-related glitch. It occurs when the mouse is moved to the top left corner and all the open windows are shown or when the start key is pressed (the same "GNOME menu" opens). These glitches are not of the same nature but this never happened on Fedora 17 either.

`lshw -c multimedia`

```
  *-multimedia            
   description: Audio device
   product: GF110 High Definition Audio Controller
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
   version: a1
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
   resources: irq:17 memory:faffc000-faffffff
  *-multimedia
   description: Audio device
   product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1b
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
   version: 05
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
   resources: irq:48 memory:fbff8000-fbffbfff
```

`aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC889 Analog [ALC889 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC889 Digital [ALC889 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High          Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
Subsystem: Giga-byte Technology Device a102
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
Memory at fbff8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
Memory at faffc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
02:00.0 IDE interface: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Device 917a (rev 11) (prog-if 8f        [Master SecP SecO PriP PriO])
```

Comment: Also on 12.04 I have noticed this too.